# Visual Basic Windows Form - Card Game - Implementing scoring rules according to two different button counters - Beginner

Tags: vb.net

- *scroll down to issues section to see my question* *

**What is my goal here?**

I am trying to write a program that will keep score for a simple two-player game (52 cards, four of each of 13 possible names, so no jokers). Jack, Queen, King and Ace are my high cards, with them, one of the two players can score points. Deck must be shuffled (so randomly select from list of cards). Player 1 turns one card first, then player B and so on. Once a card is used, it cannot be reused, so once 52 cards are pulled, the game is over. The game is scored as follows:

- if a player turns over an ace, with at least 4 cards remaining to be turned over, and none of the next 4 cards is a high card, that player scores 4 points.
- if a player turns over a king, with at least 3 cards remaining to be turned over, and none of the next 3 cards is a high card, that player scores 3 points.
- if a player turns over a queen, with at least 2 cards remaining to be turned over, and none of the next 2 cards is a high card, that player will score 2 points
- if a player turns over a jack, with at least 1 card remaining to be turned over, and the next card is not a high card, that player scores 1 point
- **note: A players own cards can also overturn a previous high card put down by himself. Say Player 1 pulls a Queen and when it's his turn again he pulls an Ace.  Then instead of scoring 2 points he has to follow the rules for when an Ace is pulled.

**What does it look like?**
[When a player button is clicked, a card name will show up in the corresponding listbox (listbox to the left for player 1 and listbox to the right for player 2). Restart button to restart program. Close button to close the program. The scores will be displayed in the bottom left in the corresponding players' label as the game goes on and a player scores.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3F7V7.jpg)

Gameplay example:

1. Player 1 pulls a three
2. Player 2 pulls a seven
3. Player 1 pulls a queen-------High Card Queen (need 2 non high cards to score 2 points)
4. Player 2 pulls a eight
5. Player 1 pulls a five-----------Player 1 just scored 2 points!
6. Player 2 pulls a Jack--------High Card Jack (need 1 non high card to score)
7. Player 1 pulls a Jack--------This jack "overwrites" the previous jack (need 1 non high card to score)
8. Player 2 pulls a seven---------Player 1 just scored 1 point!

**What code do I have until now?**

-on the right of each line under btnPLayer1_Click there is a detailed description of what the code in that line does. If for some reason you didn't get it. Similar code is used under btnPlayer2_Click

```
Public Class Form1

'Variables used during btnPlayer1_Click and btnPlayer2_Click

Dim cards As New List(Of String) From {"two", "two", "two", "two", "three", "three", "three", "three", "four", "four", "four", "four", "five", _
                         "five", "five", "five", "six", "six", "six", "six", "seven", "seven", "seven", "seven", "eight", "eight", _
                         "eight", "eight", "nine", "nine", "nine", "nine", "ten", "ten", "ten", "ten", "jack", "jack", "jack", _
                         "jack", "queen", "queen", "queen", "queen", "king", "king", "king", "king", "ace", "ace", "ace", "ace"}

Dim btn1counter As Integer
Dim btn2counter As Integer
Dim jackscore1 As Integer
Dim queenscore1 As Integer
Dim kingscore1 As Integer
Dim acescore1 As Integer
Dim jackscore2 As Integer
Dim queenscore2 As Integer
Dim kingscore2 As Integer
Dim acescore2 As Integer


'What Happens when button 1 is clicked

Private Sub btnPlayer1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPlayer1.Click
    Dim rnd = New Random()                                                    'Set rnd as random generator
    If cards.Count > 0 Then                                                   'If all cards have been drawn then no more cards can be drawn
        btn1counter += 1                                                      'Add 1 to btn1counter every time btnPlayer1 is clicked
        Dim randomcards = cards(rnd.Next(0, cards.Count))                     'Set randomcards as one randomly chosen (using rnd) card from cards list
        lstbox1.Items.Add(randomcards)                                        'Add 1 randomly chosen card from cards list into lstbox1 each time btnPlayer1 is clicked
        cards.Remove(randomcards)                                             'Remove the randomly generated card from cards list to reduce deck size. No card will be picked more than 4 times
        If randomcards.EndsWith("jack") Then                                  'If the last card picked from cards list is jack then
            Static jackcount As Integer                                       'Set jackcount as integer that will retain previous added value to it
            jackcount += 1                                                    'Add 1 to jackcount every time last card picked from cards list is jack (jackcount will never be more than 4)
            jackscore1 = jackcount * 1                                        'jackscore1 = value of jackcount times 1 (1 because jack is worth 1 point) - If 3 jacks then 1*3 = 3points
        ElseIf randomcards.EndsWith("queen") Then                             'If it wasn't jack as last card but it was queen then
            Static queencount As Integer                                      'Set queencount as integer that will retain previous added value to it
            queencount += 1                                                   'Add 1 to queencount everytime last card picked from cards list is queen (queencount will never be more than 4)
            queenscore1 = queencount * 2                                      'queenscore1 = value of queencount times 2 (2 because queen is worth 2 points) - If 3 queens then 2*3 = 6points
        ElseIf randomcards.EndsWith("king") Then                              'If it wasn't jack or queen as last card but it was king then
            Static kingcount As Integer                                       'Set kingcount as integer that will retain previous added value to it
            kingcount += 1                                                    'Add 1 to kingcount everytime last card picked from cards list is king (kingcount will never be more than 4)
            kingscore1 = kingcount * 3                                        'kingscore1 = value of kingcount times 3 (3 because king is worth 3 points) - If 3 kings then 3*3 = 9points
        ElseIf randomcards.EndsWith("ace") Then                               'If it wasn't jack or queen or king as last card but it was ace then
            Static acecount As Integer                                        'Set acecount as integer that will retain previous added value to it
            acecount += 1                                                     'Add 1 to acecount everytime last card picked from cards list is ace (acecount will never be more than 4)
            acescore1 = acecount * 4                                          'acescore1 = value of acecount times 4 (4 because ace is worth 4 points) - If 3 aces then 4*3 = 12 points
        End If
        lblScore1.Text = jackscore1 + queenscore1 + kingscore1 + acescore1    'Add all the scores gotten from jacks, queens, kings and aces and add them together in lblScore1 (player 1 score)
    End If
    lstbox1.TopIndex = lstbox1.Items.Count - 1                                'Automatically scroll down lstbox1 each time new item is added so players only see last played card (can still scroll up to see previous cards)
End Sub

'What happens when button 2 is clicked (see to right of btnPlayer1_Click code to understand each line here - same thing)

Private Sub btnPlayer2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPlayer2.Click
    Dim rnd = New Random()
    If cards.Count > 0 Then
        btn2counter += 1
        Dim randomcards = cards(rnd.Next(0, cards.Count))
        lstbox2.Items.Add(randomcards)
        cards.Remove(randomcards)
        If randomcards.EndsWith("jack") Then
            Static jackcount As Integer
            jackcount += 1
            jackscore2 = jackcount * 1
        ElseIf randomcards.EndsWith("queen") Then
            Static queencount As Integer
            queencount += 1
            queenscore2 = queencount * 2
        ElseIf randomcards.EndsWith("king") Then
            Static kingcount As Integer
            kingcount += 1
            kingscore2 = kingcount * 3
        ElseIf randomcards.EndsWith("ace") Then
            Static acecount As Integer
            acecount += 1
            acescore2 = acecount * 4
        End If
        lblScore2.Text = jackscore2 + queenscore2 + kingscore2 + acescore2
    End If
    lstbox2.TopIndex = lstbox2.Items.Count - 1
End Sub

'Button to restart program

Private Sub btnRestart_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRestart.Click
    Application.Restart()
End Sub

'Button to close program

Private Sub btnClose_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
    End
 End Sub
End Class
```

**What issues am I having?**

- How do I apply the scoring rules set earlier? for now I've only gotten each player to score points if they pull out the card... I feel like I need to use a button counter to track how many times each button is cliked after say,  a jack is pulled. I know this would be much simpler if I only had one button and one listbox but I want this to be an actual playable game, at least more so than just clicking one button. Coding the scoring process is mindnumbing, I've searched online but to no avail.. For now I've been able to count button clicks from each button with btn1counter +=1  as you can see in my code.

**Just Starting**
For your info, I literally just started programming three weeks ago. I'm starting with VB and once I get better I'll move on to Python. I really want to be a game creator in the future so all the programs I've been making have been little games like this (super simple). For now I start with a game idea, draw out the looks, set the rules I want the game to follow, and then I code it, respecting the rules I set. This is my most challenging game until now and I've hit a wall. Help is greatly appreciated :) Thank you!

Comment: `Once a card is used, it cannot be reused` you are just pulling random strings from an array which is nothing like a deck of cards.  You cant tell because there are just card ranks in the array.  Add a joker or count the number of times a King or Ace comes up and you will see.  Classes would make that more readable and understandable.

Comment: it works, trust me ive checked. if you looked at my code I have card.remove(randomcards) so it removes the randomly chosen card from the list so it can t be reused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to add a variable for tracking which card is ruling.

```
Dim rulingCard As String    
'can be "ace", "king" etc... Reset when scored / a higher card pulled 
Dim countUntilScore As Integer    
'Start from 4 for "ace". -1 for each lower card pulled.
Dim rulingCardOwner As String    
'Remember whether player1 or player2 scores when countUntilScore finished
```

Also is it necessary to separate scores for each card? Wouldn't player1Score and player2Score be enough?

Comment: I guess. My program works now, so ill leave it as it is. I kind of did what you said but different. But thanks